# The ChevronWP7 devs just discontinued the tool and Url pointing to the required Certificate

Tags: windows-phone-7

Anybody know where I can find the Certificate? I have the installer for the tool...

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest posting in response to this if you're not in a green country and want to develop WP7/Homebrew apps.

[Brandon Watson's Tweet for Devs in non green countries](http://bit.ly/eMCs77+)

Comment: The country where I live does not have Marketplace; I can't get an ID from App Hub and I'd very much like to develop homebrew apps. Unfortunately Chevron was my only way out, and now it's withdrawn

Comment: So Mick is telling you that letting Brandon know what country you're in and that at least one developer there wants marketplace access is another way to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I did not click through to twitter the first time. Anobody has had any success getting Marketplace access from outside the green zone?

Answer (score 0):

The certificate and tool have been withdrawn.

If you want to try and use it you're on your own.